# Occasionally connected application (SQL Server data synchronization)

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, merge-replication

There is a central server that is running SQL Server 2008 R2 and WinForms clients, which use SQL Server CE to cache data. Data can be changed on both the server and client side. Each user can only edit his own data and view some of the data of other users. For example, a user can create a "Contract" and upload it to the server via synchronization, other users need to see this "Contract", except for customer's contact information, etc.

What a way to synchronize data is most suitable for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Sync Framework to synchronize the local cache to a central server. You can either use the Local Database Cache Wizard in Visual Studio or code the sync yourself.

see [Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617382%28SQL.110%29.aspx)
or [Programming Common Client and Server Synchronization Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726010%28SQL.110%29.aspx)